# Analytic continuuation of an integration of an analytic function with quadratic decay

Tags: complex-analysis

let f be an analytic function in the right half plane $H=\{Re (t)\geq 0\}$ and 
$$|f(t)|\leq \frac{C}{1+|t|^2},t\in H$$, C is some constant.

Suppose that for some $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2},R>0$, f extends to be analytic in the set $$H\cup \{t:|arg t|\leq \theta + \frac{\pi}{2},|t|>R\}$$ and satisfies the same estimate.

Moreover, define the function
$$F(x)=\int_{Re(t)=0} f(t)e^{tx}dt.$$

Show that F extends to $\{z:|arg z|<\theta\}$.

There is a hint saying considering the contours $\Gamma_{R,\phi}$, which is just the boundary of the set $H\cup \{t:|arg t|\leq \phi + \frac{\pi}{2},|t|>R\}$.

I had some misunderstanding about analytic continuuation. This problem is not that hard , we only need to verify that $\int_{\Gamma_{R,\phi}} f(t)e^{tx}dt$ is well-defined for $\{x:|arg x|<\phi\}$ and coincides with F(x) when x is real. Thus the contour integral is naturally an analytic continuuation of F(x).